# Why all fields are required when using ASP.NET EF6 auto created controller and view

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am new to ASP.NET EF6 and need some help here, I created a datamodel and a datacontext

```
public class RepositoryDbContext : DbContext
{
    public RepositoryDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Repository> Repositories { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and the html page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Order</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SKU, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SKU, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SKU, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Then I used Visual Studio 2015 to auto create the controller and views, but in the create page, the sku and title are both required, how could I get rid of the required validation for Title field.

Thanks very much, I tried googling it but no luck.

Comment: I think `string? SKU` will do the trick..
you would have to update your db tho.
For more info google mvc .net data annotations...
`?` means nullable

Comment: @LiranBo `string` is a reference type . You dont need to `string?` It will no compile anyway.

Comment: Add in your question the generated html

Comment: @CodeNotFound Hi, attached the html page

Comment: It weird because your properties don't use Required data annotations. By the way just remove all `Html.ValidationMessageFor` under all `Html.Editor`